# How do you downgrade from minecraft 1.9 to 1.8 to play on servers

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Please i need  help wanna play on mineplex but 1.9 is messing it up

Answer (score 0):

When you start up the Minecraft Launcher, select "Edit Profile", and under "Version Selection", there will be a drop-down labeled "Use version:". Select the appropriate version for your server from there.

[This article](http://www.howtogeek.com/203196/how-to-change-your-minecraft-game-version-and-set-up-profiles/) might be useful if you need more detailed instructions.